# Laravel php find number between in switch case

Tags: php, laravel

User input can be two values, from `x` to `y`
Now I want to search between user entries.

For example user input are:

> from 55 to 90

Now in html select like this:

```
<select>
  <option value="1">From 5 to 50</option>
  <option value="2">From 50 to 85</option>
  <option value="3">From 85to 110</option>
</select>
```

And in controller:

```
if($request->meter){
switch ($request->meter) {
case 1:
    $query->where([
        ['meterfrom', '>=', '5'],
        ['meterto', '<=', '50']
    ]);
    break;
case 2:
    $query->where([
        ['meterfrom', '>=', '50'],
        ['meterto', '<=', '85']
    ]);
    break;
}
case 3:
    $query->where([
        ['meterfrom', '>=', '85'],
        ['meterto', '<=', '110']
    ]);
    break;
}
}
```

By this user input, my search return nothing, except those user that has data like (5-50) or (50-85) or (85-110) if user submit entry with (55-90) search can not find it, due to my switch case probably, but I wondering how to solve this? any idea or new logic to pass this?

---

**Edit:** This case about house area meter, user can enter form x meter, to y meter, for example 55 meter to 90 meter, right? now in front, I have search page, you see select option, I want to search house for example, from 5 to 50 meter or etc.. but one of user entered 55 to 90, but search by this logic can not find it.

Comment: Why you need switch case? if you want to pass x and y manually? switch case is for predefined terms but in your case, its not the case.

Comment: _“any idea or new logic to pass this?”_ - I don’t know what you are trying to ask _us_ here - what you actually want to find and based on what, that _definition_ should come from you in the first place?

Comment: We have no idea what `meterfrom` and `meterto` are supposed to be in the first place. Add a proper explanation of what those are, and what exactly you want to find based on what. Right now, I guess you perhaps might want to search for records that have _one_ of these properties in the range of x to y, maybe? But you are really making way too little sense here so far, to say anything definitive.

Comment: by my understanding, 55 to 90 you will get 2 and 3 ? is it?

Comment: @ZeroOne exactly, It should, but nothing return

Comment: @04FS I updated my post with some new explanation,

Comment: @Rahul because I use a select option to filter x from y, not by user input. I switch vase by select option value

Comment: Even your added “explanation” does not really make things clearer. _“I want to search house for example, from 5 to 50 meter or etc.. but one of user entered 55 to 90, but search by this logic can not find it.”_ - why should it, particularly for _that_ example? There is not even a partial overlap between those two intervals here.

Comment: @04FS controller logic is not clear or what I trying to do?

Comment: It is not clear what results you actually want, based on your input data, and it doesn’t help either, that you go “or etc..” in your description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution if you still want to use a select option you can use two select option like below:

```
<select name="MeterFrom">
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="50">50</option> <!-- select this -->
  <option value="85">85</option>
  <option value="110">110</option>
</select>

<select name="MeterTo">
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="50">50</option>
  <option value="85">85</option>
  <option value="110">110</option> <!-- and this -->
</select>
```

Now for find `55 to 90` you should,
select `option` 2 from `MeterFrom`
select `option` 4 from `MeterTo`

And in your controller:

```
$query->where([
    ['meterfrom', '>=', $request->meterfrom],
    ['meterto', '<=', $request->meterto]
]);
```

Actually you do not need to use `switch case` in this case *!*

Answer (score 1):

You may write else condition,

```
if ($request->meter) {
    switch ($request->meter) {
        case 1:
            $query->where([
                ['meterfrom', '>=', '5'],
                ['meterto', '<=', '50'],
            ]);
            break;
        case 2:
            $query->where([
                ['meterfrom', '>=', '50'],
                ['meterto', '<=', '85'],
            ]);
            break;
        case 3:
            $query->where([
                ['meterfrom', '>=', '85'],
                ['meterto', '<=', '110'],
            ]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
} else {
    $query->where([
        ['meterfrom', '>=', $request->x], // I hope x and y are request parameters you are getting
        ['meterto', '<=', $request->y],
    ]);
}
```

OR IN switch itself if no condition met,

```
switch ($request->meter) {
    case 1:
        $query->where([
            ['meterfrom', '>=', '5'],
            ['meterto', '<=', '50'],
        ]);
        break;
    case 2:
        $query->where([
            ['meterfrom', '>=', '50'],
            ['meterto', '<=', '85'],
        ]);
        break;
    case 3:
        $query->where([
            ['meterfrom', '>=', '85'],
            ['meterto', '<=', '110'],
        ]);
        break;
    default: // this if no condition met then go to default case
        $query->where([
            ['meterfrom', '>=', $request->x],
            ['meterto', '<=', $request->y],
        ]);
        break;
}
```

Comment: what is x and y here? I don't pass meter to controller, just pass value of select option, 1 or 2 or 3,

Answer (score 1):

> This case about house area meter, user can enter form x meter, to y meter, for example 55 meter to 90 meter, right? now in front, I have search page, you see select option, I want to search house for example, from 5 to 50 meter or etc.. but one of user entered 55 to 90, but search by this logic can not find it.

I think you don't need the select option. Just input field X and Y. Just directly query like below

```
$query->where([
        ['meterfrom', '>=', X],
        ['meterto', '<=', Y]
]);
```

You just need to pass X and Y params to controller

OR

Unless the select option is the **MULTIPLE SELECT OPTION**

Then you can pass to controller for example: selection = 2,3 // assume as string

Define arrays in controller

```
protected $restriction = [
        1 => [
            'x' => 5,
            'y' => 50
        ],
        2 => [
            'x' => 50,
            'y' => 85
        ],
        3 => [
            'x' => 85,
            'y' => 110
        ]
    ];
```

Then in your function use collection to filter based on selection input

```
//find 2,3 from the $restriction array
$options = collect($restriction)->filter(function($value, $key) {
     return in_array($key, explode(',', $this->selection)); //2,3
})->toArray();

//query based on options filtered
$query->where('meterFrom', current($options)['x'])
     ->where('meterto', end($options)['y']);
```